# Probability with Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I need some hint about Markov chains. So here is my homework.

> Let $\{ X_t : t = 0,1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}? $ be a Markov chain. What is $P(X_0 =i\mid X_n=j)$?

So I need to calculate if it's $j$ in the time of $n$ what is the probability of being $i$ at the start?

Is it :

Since if we start from state 0, then the probability to go to next state 1 is $1/2$, and to state 2 is $1/4$, etc.

$$ P_i = \left(\frac {1} {2}\right)^n \cdot \frac {1} {2}$$

Is that right ?

Comment: Is this the whole question?

Comment: Gray marked one is the whole question yes. As the prof wrote down i mean

Comment: the serie goes to n so if n th statement is j what is the probabilty of first statement being i  i guess

Comment: And what did you try? For example, would you know how to compute $P(X_n=j\mid X_0=i)$, $P(X_n=j,X_0=i)$, $P(X_n=j)$?

Comment: The probability of going to state $1$ might not be $\frac{1}{2}$ though. From state $0$, you could potentially go to any other state, or even stay in state $0$, so the probability of going to another state would be $\frac{1}{n}$, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
$P(X_0=i\mid X_n=j)=\frac{P(X_n=j\mid X_0=i)\times P(X_0=i)}{P(X_n=j)}=p_{ij}^{(n)}\times\frac{\pi_i}{\pi_j} $

Note: The Markov chain must be stationary, i.e., the chain must be in steady state.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint that will be usefull

Comment: Why call this a hint? This is a full solution (except that it does not consider the nonstationary case).

Answer (score -1):

Use Bayes theorem and decomposition matrix or probability generate function to solve it:
$$ P(X_0=i∣X_n=j) = \frac{P_{ij}^n\times P(X_0=i)}{\sum P_{ij}^n\times P(X_0=i)}$$